# How to take input in pair of float and integer in python

Tags: python

Today I'm trying to make a python program by taking a float and an integer as one input at same time. But it shows some error.

This is what I have tried:

```py
a=float,int(input("ENTER YOUR PERCENTAGE: "))
```

Comment: do you want to convert same number to integer and float? what is your input?

Comment: No i want to take a number, it might be float or integer....i am try to make a programm that show grade according to input number(float or integers).

Comment: why don't you just use float?

Comment: I want to take both.

Comment: does your input contains two number are single number

Comment: If i use only float number , then if someone try tk check their grade by percentage and entered exact number not a float . then it show error....motive is to take both float and integer

Comment: My input contain number between 1 to 100

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = input()
a = float(a) if '.' in a else int(a)
```

Comment: This solution breaks if you input two numbers separated by an space, like '2 3'. Maybe this can be included in the conditional.

Comment: if your input contain space separated numbers you can split the string then convert it

Comment: Yes, but in the way it is implemented now this is missing, and you get an exeption if `input` gets two space separated numbers, with I think is what OP asked. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @panadestein op mentioned in comment input will contain single number then only i written the solution

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you want to get a float and integer both at the same time.
Try this code.Remember `a` is stored as a tuple.Use the index to get the values stored in it.

```
a=float(input("ENTER YOUR PERCENTAGE AS FLOAT: ")),int(input("ENTER YOUR PERCENTAGE AS INT: "))
```

If you want to store them seperately all you have to do is this small change.

```
my_float, my_int=float(input("ENTER YOUR PERCENTAGE AS FLOAT: ")),int(input("ENTER YOUR PERCENTAGE AS INT: "))
```

Comment: Please make sure that you present your question correctly.You have said  that you want to take a pair."Today i am try to make a python programm by taking a ***pair*** of float and integer as a input on same time. But it show some error . So please help me to ressolve this issue."

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution (though somehow cumbersome) does exactly what you want, provided you input two numbers:

```
a = [func(float(val)) for func, val in zip([float, int],
                                input("ENTER YOUR PERCENTAGE: ").split())]
```

Note: the above code needs the additional `float(val)` inside `func` to avoid an exception that raises if the string representing the second number (that will be cast to int) contains dot characters.

Comment: if the user enter integer then your code converting it into float for 456 your code returning `[456.0]`

Comment: Quoting the original post literally, it needs to read "a pair of float and integer as a input on same time", and my code works exactly for this I think. It is only meant to solve a particular problem :)